# osgearth ThreeDTiles model data is very big

Tags: osgearth

osgearth ThreeDTiles model data is very big,Can I use LOD technology, or it uses LOD technology itself?

there is my earth file.
Model size has 3G or 4G.

```
<map name="Base Image" type="geocentric">
    <image driver = "gdal" name = "base-world" visible = "true">
        <url>./world.tif</url>
    </image>
     <ThreeDTiles name="Roads">
        <url>./ROAD/tileset.json</url>
     </ThreeDTiles>
    <ThreeDTiles name="Greend">
        <url>./house/tileset.json</url>
    </ThreeDTiles>
        <ThreeDTiles name="Building">
        <url>./city/tileset.json</url>
    </ThreeDTiles>
</map>
```

Answer (score 0):

LODs would have to be designed into the 3D-Tiles model itself. OsgEarth just loads and displays it.

3D-Tiles LODs are specified using a "geometricError" value in the 3D-Tiles tileset. If the creator used geometricError for LODs, you can specify the maximum screen-space error to use (in pixels) with the "max_sse" property on your ThreeDTiles layer.

Good luck, hope this helps.